# In Indian English, did the word 'griffin' ever mean newcomer or novice?

Tags: meaning, historical-change, subcontinental-english, nineteenth-century-english

I recently came across a definition in the dictionary Hobson-Jobson. It's basically a big collection of English words and anglicizations used or found in India. The entry that's been stumping me is the one for the word 'orombarros,' a word that looks strange even when I know what it means.

> Orombarros, s. This odd word seems to have been used as griffin (q.v.) now is. It is evidently the Malay orang-baharu, 'a new man, a novice.' This is interesting as showing an unquestionable instance of an expression imported from the Malay factories to Continental India.
>
> 1711. At Madras .... "refreshments for the Men, which they are presently supply'ed with from Country Boats and Cattamarans, who make a good Peny at the first coming of Orombarros, as they call those who have not been there before."—*Lockyer*, 28.

To me, this implies that the word 'griffin' used to mean newcomer or novice. But every dictionary I check gives me only one definition for it, which is the one about the mythical creature. So I'm very confused.

The etymology of the word provided by Merriam-Webster doesn't help me either. I thought maybe one of the roots would be useful, but none are.

Hobson-Jobson was published in the late 19th century, so that's probably the time period that you'd need to look at.

Comment: Is that a verbatim quotation from that dictionary? In any case, there are a few misspellings in it.

Comment: @Joachim - I'm not sure how the OP transcribed the quote, but it _seems_ to be verbatim. There's one error, which is that 'Penny' should have been 'Peny,' at least according to the edition I linked in my answer (page 547). I don't know if it should be changed, in case the OP's version is different from the pdf I found. 'em' for 'an' is the only other obvious mistake.

Comment: @Heartspring I just edited it using the file you linked. There were a few more typos, and some incongruences of a more superficial nature. Even if the OPs dictionary was a different version and included the mistakes, this edit doesn't have any consequence for the question.

Comment: See also “I Was Once A Griffin” by Richard Boyle: https://m.facebook.com/TheSriLankanAnchorman/posts/i-was-once-a-griffinby-richard-boyle-the-anglo-indian-word-griffin-has-intrigued/593422160852073/

Comment: ***Orombarros*** gets just 9 results in total from Google. It's not even a "known" *name*, let alone an English word.

Comment: I have a question about the 'etiquette' for editing the post. At this point, it seems that the sense of 'griffin' as in newcomer is in many different dictionaries, just not the ones that I had access to. Is it 'acceptable' or 'proper' for me to edit the question to ask more about the origin of this sense of the word? Especially since all of the answers have been addressing that as well? Or would asking for the etymology have to be a new question entirely. (Thank you by the way to the folks who answered)

Comment: It's best not to change or add to the question once answers have appeared (except perhaps for clarity). Otherwise we have a "shifting sand" situation. SE isn't a rolling dialogue. If people have included etymology in their answers, why add it to the question? And why ask a new question if you now know?

Comment: @Florian the way to thank people who answer is to upvote their post, and 'accept' an answer if you think it is the best once that answers the question.

Comment: @WeatherVane - ok, understood. I already upvoted them all, I will accept the one from TinfoilHat

Comment: I know too little about 'Indian English' to know what 'griffin' might mean there so I ask you, what does 'griffin' mean in your version of Indian English?

I say 'your version' because India being so huge, there is no useful possibility of east or west, north or south 'Indian English' matching.

The Question seems reasonable at first glance yet here, what do Anglicizations mean, please?

I don't understand how anywhere, 'griffin' could correspond to 'orombarros'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *OED* has a separate entry for *griffin* used in the sense of *newcomer*:

> **griffin**, *n.<sup>2</sup>*
>  <sub>Etymology: Of uncertain origin: usually explained as a figurative use of GRIFFIN *n.<sup>1</sup>*, but
> there is no evidence for this.</sub>
>
> *Anglo-Indian.*
>
> A European newly arrived in India, and unaccustomed to Indian ways and
> peculiarities; a novice, new-comer, greenhorn.

The second usage sample at 1794 (the first is at 1793), with its use of the word *unfledged*, suggests that at least one person associated the term with the mythical winged beast:

> <sub>1794    H. BOYD *Indian Observ.* No. 34. ⁋5    I am
> little better than an unfledged Griffin, according to the fashionable
> phrase here [*i.e.* in Madras].</sub>

The third perhaps suggests alighting, as of a bird that descends:

> <sub>1807    J. JOHNSON *Oriental Voy.* 73   
> Every arrival from Europe..as soon as he touches terra~firma is a
> griffin.</sub>

But if the *OED* can’t say where it came from, neither can I.

<sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Comment: I've accepted your answer since it is short, sweet, and succinct. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 36):

Yeah, it used to. That *q.v.* is telling you that there’s related information elsewhere in the text, so you have to ‘ctrl-f’ your way through [Hobson-Jobson](https://www.rarebooksocietyofindia.org/book_archive/196174216674_10151353402281675.pdf) to the entry for *griffin*. We get:

> *Griffin, Griff,* s. (also *Griffish*, adj.) One newly arrived in India, and unaccustomed to Indian ways and peculiarities; a Johnny Newcome.
>
> The origin of the phrase is unknown to us. There was an Admiral Griffin who commanded in the Indian seas from Nov., 1746, to June, 1748, and was not very fortunate. Had his name to do with the origin of the term? The word seems to have been first used at Madras.
> <sub>(page 303 of the book, page 357 of the pdf)</sub>

Yule and Burnell, bless them, include for us several examples. The last two are from a later edition of the dictionary:

> (1794- Hugh Boyd- Madras) "*As I am little better than an unfledged **Griffin**, according to the fashionable phrase here*"
>
> (1807- Ld. Minto in India) *"It seems really strange to a **griffin**- the cant word for a European just arrived.*"
>
> (1836- Letters from Madras) "*I often tire myself... rather than wait for their dawdling; but Mrs. Staunton laughs at me and calls me a **Griffin**,' and says I must learn to have patience and save my strength.*”
>
> (1836- Letters from Madras) "*he was living with bad men, and saw that they thought him no better than themselves, but only more **griffish.***”
>
> (1853- Oakfield, pp 38) "*There were three more cadets on  the same steamer, going up to that great **griff** depot, Oudapoor [Udaipur].*"
>
> (1853- Oakfield, pp 62) "*Ah, they don't give **griffs** half of it now-a-days; by Jove, Sir, when I was a **griff**...*"
>
> (1900- Pioneer Mail, May 18th) "*Ten Rangoon sportsmen have joined to import ponies from Australia on the **griffin** system, and have submitted a proposal to the Stewards to frame their events to be confined to **griffins** at the forthcoming autumn meeting.*"

What's interesting about these is that some of the instances are capitalized and some of them are not, and the first two mentions explain what the word means and the others do not.

So, yes, it is very likely the case that this was one of *griffin*'s old meanings, though it doesn't seem to have been used as a *generic* term for *any* newcomer; it was used mainly only to refer to Westerners in India. I should mention that I've never once in my life heard it used like that even though I spend quite a lot of time in India, and this sense of the word has probably died out.

(The sense of 'novice' seems to be limited to just *orombarros*, no definition for griffin includes this.)

It also pops up in the forward, where the authors imply that the sense was at least *somewhat* known in England:

> A certain percentage of such [Indianisms]  have been carried to England by the constant reflux to their native shore of Anglo-Indians, who in some degree imbue with their notions and phraseology the circles from which they had gone forth.
>
> Of words that seem to have been admitted to full franchise, we may give examples in *curry, toddy, veranda, cheroot, loot, nabob, teapoy, sepoy, coury;* and of others familiar enough to the English ear, though hardly yet received into citizenship, *compound, batta, pucka, chowry, baboo, mahout, aya, nautch, first-chop, competition-wallah, **griffin,*** &c.

*Griffin* is also in the addendum and an entry for *reinol*, a word that it seems to be synonymous too. I haven't included those as they add nothing to the definition given above.

Also see [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Viertalig_aanvullend_hulpwoordenboek_voo/XVh81bOnOMIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=griffin%20orombarros&pg=PA13&printsec=frontcover), [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Vestiges_of_Old_Madras/Bl9T4uJcBFAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=orombarros&pg=PA85&printsec=frontcover), and [this](https://www.cambridgescholars.com/product/978-1-5275-5702-4) book titled '*Charles D’Oyly’s Lost Satire of British India: Tom Raw, the Griffin, 1828*.'

---

As for that Admiral Griffin theory: This seems to be referring to [Admiral Thomas Griffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Griffin_(Royal_Navy_officer)) (who rather resembles a frigatebird). He did indeed serve in Madras, but I can't find any other supporting evidence for this. What makes me a little inclined to doubt the idea that the word itself originated in Madras is that Madras is a predominantly Tamil-speaking city, and there's no native /f/ sound in Tamil. This isn't to say that they can't pronounce it, but most Tamilian accents will pronounce words such as 'tiffin' as /tɪpən/. This includes Tamil speakers in Chennai.

---

It's not in any of the major dictionaries, but it is in [Dictionary.com's](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/griffin#:%7E:text=griffin%202,person%20from%20a%20Western%20country.) second entry for griffin:

> (in India and the East) a newcomer, especially a white person from a Western country.
>
> First recorded in 1785–95; origin uncertain
>
> *griffinage, griffinhood, griffinism, griffinish*

And from Wiktionary:

> **[griffin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/griffin)**: (dated, India) A person who has just arrived from Europe.
>
> **[griff](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/griff)**: (India) griffin, (white) newcomer.
>
> **[griffish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/griffish)**: (India, dated) Resembling or characteristic of a griff or griffin, a white person newly arrived in India from Europe.

Comment: Seems to be exclusive to new arrivals in India.  Are there examples of it being used in any other context?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - what do you mean by 'any other context'? Do you mean used for new arrivals in, say, Thailand? Or whether there are any instances of it being used as a generic term for _any_ newcomer, regardless of where they are from and where they are new to?

Comment: The OP was asking about its use in terms of meaning a newcomer or novice - "newcomer" would not necessarily be geographically specific to just India, and "novice" might not involve travel at all.  But all of the examples seem to imply Europeans new to India specifically.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - agreed; I've clarified that in my answer.

Comment: What a wonderful answer. It seems likely that the Admiral's inexperience led to his name being used as a shorthand for "inexperienced newcomer" but I can't prove that and neither can the OED. Some things are lost to time.

Comment: @Ben - How kind of you to say :) It's hard to think of any other theory, and this seems the least dubious. (Also, poor Admiral!)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the term ***[griffin](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/tdzkata)*** also griff is of Anglo-Indian origin:

> 1. (Anglo-Ind.) a newcomer to India who is ignorant of Anglo-Indian ways; orig. used of freshly arrived young officers but adopted through society; also attrib.

Early usage examples:

> 1793  [UK]    Major Child in Southey Life of A. Bell (1844) I 459: *Wilks, who is on the spot [i.e. Pondicherry] and who will [...] lend you every assistance in forwarding these matters, in which, unless I am mistaken, you must, I presume, be a perfect griffin.*
>
> 1807  [Ind]   G. Elliot in Minto Lord Minto in India (1880) 17: *I was not prepared for the entire nakedness of the Gentoo inhabitants. [...] It seems really strange to a griffin – the cant word for a European just arrived.*
>
> 1824  [UK]    Lit. Chron. (London) 22 May 335/2: *All new comers in India are called Griffins, and they must be a twelvemonth and a day in the country, before they are considered free from the title.*

Latest usage are from early 20th c.

> 1906  [Ind]   Civil & Milit. Gaz. (Lahore) 17 Jan. 7/3: *[O]nly a griffin, a tourist or a travelling M. P. would fall into the error of imagining that the gaze’'s thoughts are centred on aught loftier than paisa, bakshish and the like.*
>
> 1911  [Ind]   Civil & Milit. Gaz. (Lahore) 16 Apr. 10/1: *The veriest griffin has heard of the intractable humour of the Abors.*

(Green’s Dictionary of Slang)

From Hobson-Jobson Dictionary

1. ***[GRIFFIN, GRIFF](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/hobsonjobson_query.py?qs=GRIFFIN,%20GRIFF&searchhws=yes&matchtype=exact) (p. 396)***

> GRIFFIN, GRIFF, s.; GRIFFISH , adj. One newly arrived in India, and unaccustomed to Indian ways and peculiarities; a Johnny Newcome. The origin of the phrase is unknown to us. There was an Admiral Griffin who commanded in the Indian seas from Nov. 1746 to June 1748, and was not very fortunate. Had his name to do with the origin of the term? The word seems to have been first used at Madras (see Boyd, below). [But also see the quotation from Beaumont & Fletcher, below.] Three references below indicate the parallel terms formerly used by the Portuguese at Goa, by the Dutch in the Archipelago, and by the English in Ceylon.

> [c. 1624. — "Doves beget doves, and eagles eagles, Madam: a citizen's heir, though never so rich, seldom at the best proves a gentleman." — Beaumont & Fletcher, Honest Man's Fortune, Act III. sc. 1, vol. iii. p. 389, ed. Dyce. Mr. B. Nicolson (3 ser. Notes and Queries, xi. 439) points out that Dyce's MS. copy, licensed by Sir Henry Herbert in 1624, reads "proves but a griffin gentleman." Prof. Skeat (ibid. xi. 504) quoting from Piers Plowman, ed. Wright, p. 96, "Gryffyn the Walshe," shows that Griffin was an early name for a Welshman, apparently a corruption of Griffith. The word may have been used abroad to designate a raw Welshman, and thus acquired its present sense.]

Answer (score 1):

Noting that Griffin as a term was also used in places like Shanghai and Hong Kong - clearly an import from India. Interestingly, both places also use the term for new race horses imported to both cities in the late 1880s - to 1940s, and is still in use in Hong Kong today - http://www.hkroa.org/en/racehorse_ownership.php.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).